# Mobile site speed affected by use of plugins

Tags: pagespeed-insights, page-load-time

Can using a lot of plugins on a WordPress site affect your mobile page speed load time adversely? What is the best solution to 'Minimize main-thread work'?

Answer (score 2):

These questions are *extremely broad* and are therefore difficult to answer in a useful way. I will attempt to do so anyway.

> Can using a lot of plugins on a WordPress site affect your mobile page speed load time adversely?

Yes. So can using a small number of plugins that do complicated work. So can using one awful plugin that is poorly written. So can having the site hosted on the moon. The only way you can know with certainty is to do testing, with measurements.

> What is the best solution to “Minimize main-thread work”

To do less work in the main-thread. The “main-thread” is the one that loads and renders the page. How to do that depends on what your page is doing.

Do you have a lot of JavaScript on your page? Parsing JavaScript is really, really slow, and phones can’t do it as fast as other machines. If your WordPress plugins use a lot of JavaScript, that would probably cause your problem.

**We can’t answer this question any more specifically than this without knowing exactly what your page does and what it actually needs to do.**

Comment: Site hosted on the moon , very good - up vote  